# Can I store `/.github` outside of repo root dir?

Tags: github

My repo uses a `/.github` [folder](https://github.com/aiqc/AIQC/tree/main/.github) at the project root, but I am trying to slim down the top level contents of root and I don't want a `.` hidden directory to be the first thing people see.

- Can I move this to another location like `/dev`?
- If so, do I need to specify its location in a configuration?

---

I took a look at my project settings and this documentation, but didn't see anything obvious:

> https://docs.github.com/en/communities/setting-up-your-project-for-healthy-contributions/creating-a-default-community-health-file

Comment: No. But a comment needs to be longer than that.

Answer (score 0):

You can, of course, adopt nearly any layout for your repository that you like.  However, GitHub doesn't look in other folders for the contents of the `.github` directory, only in the top level, so if you want those to work with GitHub, then you need to have them in a location that it uses.